# ZF 1 Unable to chain to Route_Module to get a Id field

Tags: zend-framework, zend-route

I have two modules in ZF 1 one is a module the other is the initial application itself my problem is I need to have a Id dynamic number submited after an action when editing interacting with record.

The code bellow is not working I can't understand where the problem is... Any ideas or sugestions?
**not working = the id part is not recognized**

```
protected function _initRoutes()
    {
        $ctrl = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();

        $router = $ctrl->getRouter();

        $primary = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Module(
                array()
                ,$ctrl->getDispatcher()
                ,$ctrl->getRequest()
                );

        $secondary = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
                ':id', array( 'id' =>  "\d+" ) 
                );

        $primary->chain($secondary);

        $router->addRoute("default", $primary);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that the module route includes the standard wildcard on the end, which matches key/value pairs (`:module/:controller/:action/*`), so this route matches the whole of your URL, and since there's nothing for the second route to match against, the overall match fails.

You really gain nothing by using route chaining here. You'd be better off just using Zend_Controller_Router_Route:

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    ':module/:controller/:action/:id',
    array(
        'module' => 'default',
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'index'
    ),
    array(
        'id' =>  "\d+"
    ) 
);
$router->addRoute('default', $route);
```

Comment: Hello, I already tryed this and the application fails stops matching any route.

"Zend_Controller_Router_Exception: No route matched the request " This happens when I try what you sugested, and if I try 
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
                        ':module/:controller/:action/:id',
                        array(
                            'module'        => 'default'
                            ,'controller'   => 'index'
                            ,'action'       => 'index'
                            ,'id' => "\d+")
        );
It requires a module to be specified.

Comment: Yes you will need to include a module in the URL - do you not want this to be there?

Comment: My default module is in the application directory the others I'm adding them now.